# Can I convert a string to float in HTML with Javascript and get Square Root?

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to JavaScript and I have a problem. I want a user to input a number into a text input box and when they click a button, an alert box appears telling the Square Root of their number. The problem is, when the box appears, the message says 'NaN'? Can somebody help?

```
function convert(){
  var userInput = Number(document.getElementById("sqrinput"));
  alert(Math.sqrt(parseFloat(userInput)));
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `document.getElementById("sqrinput")` returns the DOM element itself, not the value of the input field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11563638/218196)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `value` of the `#sqrinput` element:

```js
function convert() {
  var userInput = Number(document.getElementById("sqrinput").value);
  alert(Math.sqrt(parseFloat(userInput)));
}
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", convert);
```

```html
<input id="sqrinput" />
<button id="btn">Square</button>
```